# Setting "Negotiate multi-link for single-link connections" through DotRas

Tags: c#, ras

I'm creating a dialup entry in the ras phonebook, using DotRas.

Everything works fine, only i can't figure out how to set that option.

When i create the connection manually in windows and check that option in the PPP Settings everything works.

If it's not checked, no internet access.

Using RasEntry to define the entry.
Opening RasPhoneBook (user) so there are no problem with user rights.

Comment: Resloved, case of sleepy eyes missing text in the docs XD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens on win2k lib. Simple solution is to use the WinXP lib, and set DoNotNegotiateMultilink flag.

Tho doing this sets the minimum requirement to winXP.